# Query rows where time is between two times (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I need to query all entries from January 1 to January 31. But only between 6 am to 10 am for each day. I should do it in MySQL.

Comment: It would be good if you can tell us what you have tried, you query could be something as simple as SELECT * FROM table WHERE datacol BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31' ...

Answer (score 30):

Use the `BETWEEN` operator to match between values. And use the `HOUR()` function to get the hour out of the dates.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00' AND '2015-01-31 23:59:59'
AND HOUR(date) BETWEEN 6 AND 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this query to get all rows.

```
SELECT * FROM `attendance_raw` WHERE date>='2016-09-08 10:00:00' AND date<='2016-09-09 06:00:00'
```

Comment: This would query from 10am on 2016-09-08 to 6am on 2016-09-09 rather than between 6am and 10am on each of those days.